# how can I iterate through all objects in a json response in python

Tags: python, json

I have been banging my head pretty hard against the wall trying to figure out why I can get some attributes but not all in a json response(in Python)

For example: when running the code in the below function, the 3 attributes I am getting here and found successfully(_id, state, type, and name) are all on the same level as some other attributes, however it seems I cannot get the other attributes.  (See full json response below the function.)

Values I cant get are for scan_progress_status, parent_scan_id, parent_scan_type

```
getScans = scans.get_scans()
scanResults = json.loads(getScans)
results = {}

for x in scanResults['scans']:
    results.update({x['_id'][0:]: {
       'state': x['state'],
       'name': x['name'],
       'type': x['type'],
       'parent_scan_id': x['parent_scan_id']
       
    }
})
y = json.dumps(results)
scanStates = cj.convert_pretty_json(y)

return scanStates
```

**RESPONSE**

```
    {
  "scans": [
    {
      "_id": "60c40198152afeca2e5f2cfd",       
      "classification_is_enabled": true,       
      "connectorType": "rdb-postgresql",       
      "created_at": "2021-06-12T00:36:40.322Z",
      "customConnectorType": "default",        
      "ds_connection_name": "client_id_test",  
      "ds_location": null,
      "identityConnectionsUuid": [],
      "isDifferential": false,
      "isSampling": false,
      "name": "GenericScanner Subscan 1/1: client_id_test",
      "number_of_parsing_threads": 2,
      "origin": "client_id_test",
      "parent_scan_id": "60c40198152afeca2e5f2ce7",
      "parent_scan_type": "full_scan",
      "profile_id": null,
      "row_identifier_expression_is_disabled": false,
      "scanSecretKey": "masked0a0VT24aOvlg==",
      "scan_progress_status": {
        "Queued": "2021-06-12T00:36:40.322Z",
        "CollectingMetadata": "2021-06-12T00:36:44.239Z"
      },
      "scanner_group": "default",
      "scanner_type_group": "structured",
      "state": "CollectingMetadata",
      "structured_clustering_enabled": false,
      "type": "sub_scan",
      "updated_at": "2021-06-12T00:36:44.364Z",
      "startTimestamp": 1623458200354,
      "enumerationState": "Completed",
      "scan_enumeration_progress_status": {
        "Started": "2021-06-12T00:36:44.239Z",
        "Completed": "2021-06-12T00:36:44.364Z"
      },
      "scannerId": "4340cbb7-5949-4412-8ddf-afd36dd16d1c",
      "latestCollectionScanned": {
        "fullyQualifiedName": "client_id_test.public.clients",
        "totalRows": null,
        "totalRowsWithFindings": null
      },
      "scannedSize": 0,
      "totalCollections": 0,
      "totalEnumerated": 1,
      "totalFailedCollections": 0,
      "totalFindings": 0,
      "totalRows": 0,
      "totalRowsWithFindings": 0,
      "scan_parts_counter": {
        "New": 1
      }]}
```

What makes parent_scan_id, and some of the others different enough that it would cause Key Errors?

Comment: pls check the typos. for example `x['state']` and `x['type']` is not present on the RESPONSE json. also, there is a single quote missing on `x['parent_scan_id]`. are you getting a key error? if so pls check if that field is present in the JSON. rest looks okay on your code.

Comment: Also, missing square and curly brackets.  'false' should be 'False'.  'null' should be 'None'.  This might seem nitpicky, but if your data/code doesn't execute as shown, it begs the question whether it runs for you.

Comment: Those were just my typos, the response coming back is Valid, looks like I left out some of the response in the example.  Updated.  Thank you

Comment: The response in this question is a valid response from the webserver.   My question is not about a broken response, I am trying parse through this response and seeing key errors for some attributes, but not others. @RustyB

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be the attributes like 'parent_scan_id" where I was getting key errors was because some blocks did not have this attribute.

The Solution was to set a variable to parent_scan_id, and if it exists then update my results object

```
 for x in scanResults['scans']:
    parent_scan_id = x['parent_scan_id'] if 'parent_scan_id' in x else 'undefined'
    results.update({x['_id'][0:]: {
       'state': x['state'],
       'name': x['name'],
       'type': x['type'],
       'parent_scan_id': parent_scan_id
       
    }
})
```